# Unable to fix the scroll bar at the bottom of chat box(div)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I'm working on chat application. On loading my PHP file I want to fix the scroll bar at the bottom of div. I have written the script to do this. I'm accessing it using CSS Id but I'm unable to make it work.

**Code**

```
//Css part
<style>
.msg-wgt-body {
 height: 300px;
 overflow-y: scroll;}
</style>

<script>
$(".1").scrollTop($('.1').height())
</script>

<div class="container" style="border: 1px solid lightgray;">
<div class="msg-wgt-header">
<a href="#">Kaps</a>
</div>
<div class="msg-wgt-body" id="1">
<table>
<?php
if (!empty($messages)) {
foreach ($messages as $message) {
$msg = htmlentities($message['message'], ENT_NOQUOTES);
$user_name = ucfirst($message['username']);   
$sent =  date("F j, Y, g:i a", strtotime($message['sent_on']));

echo <<<MSG
          <tr class="msg-row-container">
            <td>
              <div class="msg-row">
                <div class="avatar"></div>
                <div class="message">
       <span class="user-label"><a href="#" style="color: #6D84B4;">
    {$user_name}</a> <span class="msg-time">{$sent}</span></span><br/>{$msg}
          </div>
              </div>
            </td>
          </tr>
 MSG;

        }
      }

      else {
        echo '<span style="margin-left: 25px;">No chat messages available!
</span>';
      }


      ?>

    </table>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this using your CSS -Class as well.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
        $(".msg-wgt-body").scrollTop($('.msg-wgt-body')[0].scrollHeight);

   return false;
});
</script>
```

Use this above code and add this at the bottom of your PHP file(You can add this in your JS file as well). Try this it should work.

Answer (score 0):

I guest you want scroll down to the bottom when the chats loaded, right!

**Just replace this**

```
</style>
      <script> $(".1").scrollTop($('.1').height()) 
</script>
```

**with**

```
<script>
   $("#1").scrollTop($('#1')[0].scrollHeight);
</script>
```

Comment: No i want scroll down when i load my php file and also i checked this also but not working

Comment: that is what i mean, i used the code above and when even i  load my chats it scroll the content to the last chat just as in whatsapp

Comment: The result why it doesn't work is because you used **.1** instead of **#1** the **1** is CSS **id** not **class**